# Sanitizing string to url safe format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to sanitize a string so that it can be used to be put in an URL. This is just for show in the URL. Now I was using this function in PHP which worked fine:

```
$CleanString = IconV('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $String);
$CleanString = Preg_Replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $CleanString);
$CleanString = StrToLower( Trim($CleanString, '-') );
$CleanString = Preg_Replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $Delimiter, $CleanString);
```

Now I am trying to put this in C#, the regex's are no problem but the first line is a bit tricky. What is the safe way to replace characters as é á ó with their normal equivalents a e o?

For example, above would transer:

```
The cát ís running & getting away
```

to

```
the-cat-is-running-getting-away
```

Comment: Check out: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/non-us-ascii-characters-dropped-from-full-profile-url/7696#7696

Comment: thanks! that will do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c)` method can tell you if a character is a "Non spacing mark". This can only be used when the string is in a form where accents ("diacritics") are separated from their letter, which can be obtained with `Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)`.

Here is the full string extension method:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;
...

public static string RemoveDiacritics(this string strThis)
{
    if (strThis == null)
        return null;

    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (char c in strThis.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD))
    {
        if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
            sb.Append(c);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution. You might, however, improve it depending on your needs by adding a check for `UnicodeCategory.OtherPunctuation` in the foreach block. This will remove those annoying &'s, commas, extra dashes etc that might casue IIS to throw errors. But if you go with it, don't forget to replace double spaces when returning the value by doing `return sb.ToString().Replace("  ", " ")` or something similar.